# Do Attachments move with CI's

Tags: servicenow

We have attachments attached to CIs and when we perform Discovery, those CIs will move into their appropriate Class table. Will the attachments attached to those CIs move with them?

Answer (score 0):

No.  You will need to add a business rule to `cmdb_ci` after update to find any records on `sys_attachment` where the `table_sys_id` is the current.getValue('sys_id'), and the table is the previous.getTableName(), then update that `sys_attachment` record to point to the new table `current.getTableName()`

Comment: I should add, normally I don't see folks adding attachments to configuration items but each business has it's reasons to do these things.